# Next.js ISR: what's happening under the hood

Tags: next.js, vercel

> To use ISR, add the revalidate prop to getStaticProps https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration

I imagine that when a request comes in, the CDN data centre checks if the cached page is stale and if so triggers a regeneration by a regional lambda (sending out the stale page to the request that triggers the regeneration).

I'm thinking it's unlikely that regenerated page gets sent out to every data centre of the CDN.

So when does the newly generated page get sent out to the CDN.

Also how does on demand revalidation work?